# Controller link is getting repeat after click on the other page link

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am facing a problem while clicking on a link.
**when i click on below link.. then it is working fine.**

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('Main_controller/chronicles') ?>" >Chronicles</a>
```

but after this when i click on the other link.. then the controller is repeating twice in url.
for ex: when I click on this link..

```
<a href="<?php base_url(); ?>index.php/Main_controller/load_compliance">SEMINAIRES  <br/>PASSS</a>
```

then the url link change to: 
http://[::1]/competence/index.php/Main_controller/index.php/Main_controller/load_compliance

Comment: Try removing `index.php`

Comment: You need to set the base url in the config.php `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/'`

Comment: why you use `base_url();` if you don't even echo it's value

Answer (score 1):

You need to echo

**Replace:**

```
<a href="<?php base_url(); ?>index.php/Main_controller/load_compliance">SEMINAIRES  <br/>PASSS</a>
```

**With:**

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Main_controller/load_compliance">SEMINAIRES  <br/>PASSS</a>
```

**OR:** *(if you don't want to write echo)*

```
<a href="<?= base_url(); ?>index.php/Main_controller/load_compliance">SEMINAIRES  <br/>PASSS</a>
```

### Update:

As **@DeadManAlive** pointed out and I looked it up.

Your URL like `http://[::1]/index.php` 
indicates that your `$config['base_url']` in `config/config.php` is set to empty string.

Comment: it cause  because of `base_url` is empty

Comment: Thnx, It Worked.

Comment: @Tanmay consider it accepting as answer. You're welcome.